# Django Burger Menu with JavaScript Static

Tags: javascript, css, django, django-templates

I am writing a Django website. I am trying to use a JavaScript file to move a mobile nav bar into the page when clicking on the burger icon.

I have successfully loaded a JavaScript file from the static folder. (I checked with the alert function.)

However, once I write more code in the JavaScript file, the JavaScript file doesn't work and I don't get the alert "Hello, javascript file loaded" upon refreshing the website page. Is my javascript incorrect? Is the format incorrect for use in Django?

Any help would be much appreciated, thanks for reading.

**App.js**

```
alert("Hello, javascript file loaded");  


const navSlide = () => {
    const burger = document.querySelector('.burger');
    const nav = document.querySelector('.nav-links');

    burger.addEventListener('click', () = > {
        nav.classList.toggle('nav-active');
    }); 
}

navSlide();
```

**Base.html**

```
{% load static %}
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Pep Genie</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'genie/style.css' %}">
    </head>

    <body>

        {% block content %}{% endblock %}

        <script src="{% static 'genie/app.js' type="text/javascript" %}"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

**Index.html**

```
{% extends 'genie/base.html' %}
{% block content %}

<nav>
    <div class="logo">
        <h4>The Logo</h4>
    </div>
    <ul class="nav-links">
        <li>
            <a href="#">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">About</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">Work</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">Our Projects</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <div class="burger">
        <div class="line1"></div>
        <div class="line2"></div>
        <div class="line3"></div>
    </div>

</nav>
```

**Style.css**

```
* {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
 }

nav {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    align-items: center;
    min-height: 8vh;
    background-color: navy;
    color: lightgray;
    font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing: 5px;
    font-size: 20px;
}

nav .logo {
    margin: 0 100px 0 0;
}

.nav-links {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    width: 40%;  
}

nav li {
    list-style: none;
}

nav a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: lightgray;
    letter-spacing: 3px;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 14px;
}

.burger {
    display: none;
}

.burger div {

    width: 25px;
    height: 2px;
    margin: 4px;
    background-color: lightgray;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1000px) {
    .nav-links {
        width: 50%;
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    body {
        overflow-x: hidden;
    }
    .nav-links {
        position: absolute;
        right: 0;
        top: 8vh;
        height: 92vh;
        background-color: navy;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        align-items: center;
        width: 50%;
        transform: translateX(100%);
        transition: transform 0.5s ease-in;
    }

    .burger {
        display: block;
        cursor: pointer;
    }
}

.nav-active {
    transform: translateX(0%);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function navSlide(){
    const burger = document.querySelector('.burger');
    const nav = document.querySelector('.nav-links');

    burger.addEventListener('click', function(){
        nav.classList.toggle('nav-active');
        console.log('event triggered');
    }); 
}

navSlide();
```

```css
    * {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
 }

nav {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    align-items: center;
    min-height: 8vh;
    background-color: navy;
    color: lightgray;
    font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing: 5px;
    font-size: 20px;
}
.burger {
        display: none;
    }
nav .logo {
    margin: 0 100px 0 0;
}

.nav-links {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    width: 40%;  
}

nav li {
    list-style: none;
}

nav a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: lightgray;
    letter-spacing: 3px;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 14px;
}


.burger div {

    width: 25px;
    height: 2px;
    margin: 4px;
    background-color: lightgray;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1000px) {
    .nav-links {
        width: 50%;
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    body {
        overflow-x: hidden;
    }
    .nav-links {
        position: absolute;
        right: 0;
        top: 8vh;
        height: 92vh;
        background-color: navy;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        align-items: center;
        width: 50%;
        transform: translateX(100%);
        transition: transform 0.5s ease-in;
    }

    .burger {
        display: block;
        cursor: pointer;
        background: red;
    }
}

.nav-active {
    transform: translateX(0%);
}
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Pep Genie</title>

    </head>

    <body>

        <nav>
    <div class="logo">
        <h4>The Logo</h4>
    </div>
    <ul class="nav-links">
        <li>
            <a href="#">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">About</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">Work</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">Our Projects</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <div class="burger">
        <div class="line1"></div>
        <div class="line2"></div>
        <div class="line3"></div>
    </div>

</nav>
    </body>
</html>
```

I don't know about django and your js style is strange but the classic way tha works would look like this:

```
function navSlide(){
const burger = document.querySelector('.burger');
const nav = document.querySelector('.nav-links');

burger.addEventListener('click', function(){
    nav.classList.toggle('nav-active');
});
```

}

Please check this example, in the console you can see the triggered event on click burger-menu: https://jsfiddle.net/yf9wo67a/

Comment: Thanks ÿmit for your answer! Your code does luck much nicer. I pasted it into my project, and no change. The alert "Hello, javascript file loaded" did not appear upon refresh. Thank you anyway

Comment: You can use a linter tool like jshint.com to check if your code is valid

Comment: Hi ÿmit, thanks for the example. It see it does work. Since the code doesn't work in my vs code, I think the problem must be Django specific. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there might be a problem with this line:

```
<script src="{% static 'genie/app.js' type="text/javascript" %}"></script>
```

The type="" section should be separate form the src, as follows:

```
<script src="{% static 'genie/app.js' %}" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: Hi Ffion, Thank you so much for your reply. I've corrected the mistake, but sadly there is no change.

Comment: You're welcome. Hmmm, the JavaScript code itself looks ok. Do you see any errors in the console? That would be a useful way to check if the js file is indeed being found and loaded. If you'e in Google Chrome, you can right-click on the screen, click 'Inspect' and then click on the 'Console' tab to see this.

Answer (score 0):

***Pure CSS Burger Menu in Django***

Found a work around by by using a pure CSS responsive nav bar with the :target pseudo class.

Here's my sources:

1. Mark Caron: Pure CSS Hamburger Menu. https://medium.com/@heyoka/responsive-pure-css-off-canvas-hamburger-menu-aebc8d11d793
2. Mozilla MDN Web Docs: the CSS :target peudo-class. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:target

Instead of using the JavaScript function with onclick, you can set your burger icon inside an anchor tag, and set the href to and url fraction like "#mobile-menu". Then, to make the url fraction cause a change (like changing your menu display from none to block for example) you can use the CSS :target pseudo class. Add this to your CSS.

```
.mobile-menu:target{
    display: flex;
}
```

This references an id, so it is essential that your menu has an id set to "mobile-menu". This can now make the menu appear on clicking the burger.

Here is my full code for reference:

***index.html***

```
{% extends 'genie/base.html' %}
{% block content %}


<nav>
    <div class="logo">
        <h4>The Logo</h4>
    </div>
    <ul class="nav-links" id="nav-links">
        <li>
            <a href="#">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">About</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">Work</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">Our Projects</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <a class="burger" href="#nav-links">
        <div class="line1"></div>
        <div class="line2"></div>
        <div class="line3"></div>
    </a>

</nav>


{% endblock %}
```

***base.html***

```
{% load static %}
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Pep Genie</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'genie/style.css' %}">
        <link rel="javascript" type="text/javascript" href="{% static 'genie/app.js' %}">
    </head>

    <body>
        
        {% block content %}{% endblock %}

        <script src="{% static 'genie/app.js' %}" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

***style.css***

```
* {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
 }



 nav {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
  min-height: 8vh;
  background-color: navy;
  color: lightgray;
  font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 5px;
  font-size: 20px;
}

nav .logo {
  margin: 0 100px 0 0;
}

.nav-links {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  width: 40%;  
}

nav li {
  list-style: none;
}

nav a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: lightgray;
  letter-spacing: 3px;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 14px;
}

.burger {
  display: none;
}

.burger div {

  width: 25px;
  height: 2px;
  margin: 4px;
  background-color: lightgray;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1000px) {
  .nav-links {
      width: 50%;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  body {
      overflow-x: hidden;
  }
  .nav-links {
      position: absolute;
      right: 0;
      top: 8vh;
      height: 92vh;
      background-color: navy;
      display: none;
      flex-direction: column;
      align-items: center;
      width: 50%;

  }

  .burger {
      display: block;
      cursor: pointer;
  }
}

.nav-links:target{
    display: flex;
}
```